# Making Google Charts look like Google Stocks?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

If you look a stock on Google (eg. [search for 'Apple stocks'](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=apple+stocks)) you get a rather nice and interactive looking chart like so:

[image]

Note the vertical crosshair and great looking tooltip.

Trying to get something similar on Google Charts (which I naively(?) assumed used the same technology) is proving much more difficult.

[image]

Yes, it's not a million miles away, but there's no vertical crosshairs, or any of the other nice touches which make Google's native stock charts look so nice.

Here's my current working: http://jsfiddle.net/6vpjyvLe/

```
  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Test Chart',
      subtitle: 'with some random times and figures'
    },
      legend: {
          position: 'none'
      },
      crosshair: {
          orientation: 'vertical'
      },
      animation: {
          startup: true,
          duration: 5000
      },
    width: 500,
    height: 300

  };
```

I've been following the [Google Charts Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Material), but nothing I've tried there appears to work. I can't even animate the chart to add style that way.

Is it possible to style them the same?

Answer (score 1):

The tooltips in Google Charts are absolutely very customizable.  By setting the 'tooltip.isHtml: true' you can manipulate the tooltip output with HTML markup.  Google has a breakdown of how to do it [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content).